# array is returning an extra value

Tags: c, arrays, input

I am calling functions to get an array from the user and to manipulate that array. My problem is that I am trying to get 10 integers from the user. After the 10 integers are entered, another random integer (maybe a memory location?) is automatically added to the end of my array. As you can see the 2686672 has been added by the gods. I am not real sure where my problem is.

my output is actually listed at the top of the code. I tried to post a pic of the output but I'm a newb so I am not allowed to do that.

```
The values of the array as entered are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2686672
The values of the sorted array are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2686672
The largest number in the set is 2686672
The smallest number in the set is 1
The average of the number set is 244247.906250
The standard deviation of the number set is 244242.406250
10
```

The code:

```
// include libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// declare functions
int max (int count, int array[]);
int min (int count, int array[]);
int getArray (int array[]);
float stDev (int count, int array[]);
float avg (int count, int array[]);
void printArray (int count, int array[]);
void sortArray (int count, int array[]);


int main()
{
    // declare variables and arrays
    int count = 10;
    int array[count];

    // Give user instructions
    printf("Please enter an integer followed by the enter key.\n");
    printf("User input will halt after ten integers, \nor if a number less than zero is entered.\n");
    count = getArray(array);                // call function to get user input
    printf("The values of the array as entered are: ");
    printArray (count, array);             // call function to print array as it was entered
    sortArray (count, array);              // call function to sort the array
    printf("The values of the sorted array are: ");
    printArray (count, array);             // call function to print the sorted array
    printf("The largest number in the set is %d\n", max (count, array));       // call function and print the max value
    printf("The smallest number in the set is %d\n", min (count, array));       // call function and print the min value
    printf("The average of the number set is %f\n", avg(count, array));         // call function and print the average value
    printf("The standard deviation of the number set is %f\n", stDev (count, array));     // call function and print the standard deviation
    printf("%d",count);

    return 0;
}
//****************** FUNCTIONS *************************


/*
Function name: getArray
Inputs: The address array[0]
Outputs: Integers entered for the array. Up to 10 integers
Description: This function gets user values for the array for up to 10 separate integers.\
             If a negative number, that will be the last input allowed.
*/

int getArray(int array[]){
    int N=10, c;          // declare local variables
    // for loop that places the integer input into the array
    for( c=0; c<N; c++){
        scanf("%d", &array[c]); // place input into array location for that particular loop
        // if a negative number is entered, force for loop end
        if (array[c]<0)
            N=c;

    }
    return c;       // return the # of integers entered
}


/*
Function name: avg
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Outputs: The average value of the array contents
Description: This function serves to take the individual integers in the array, add them
             all together, and divide by the number of integers i.e. find the mean value
             of the array.
*/

float avg(int count, int array[]){
    int c;      // set counter to integer
    float temp = 0.0;   // set temp to float
    // for loop that adds all the integers in the array
    for (c=0; c<= count; c++){
        temp = temp + array[c];     // add current value of the array to temp
    }
    temp = (temp / c);              // divide added integers by the number of integers
    return temp;                    // return the mean value of the array
}


/*
Function name: max
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Output: the max value of the integers in the array
Description: This function serves to find the maximum value of the array
             by comparing every integer to the current maximum.
*/
int max (int count, int array[]){
    int temp = array[0], c;     // declare variables and set the first integer of the array to max
    // for loop to compare current max to current integer
    for (c=1; c<= count; c++){
        // if the integer at the current array address is larger than the current max, replace it
        if (array[c] > temp)
            temp = array[c];
    }
    return temp;        // return max value of the array
}

/*
Function name: min
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Output: the min value of the integers in the array
Description: This function serves to find the minimum value of the array
             by comparing every integer to the current minimum.
*/
int min (int count, int array[]){
    int temp = array[0], c;     // set the first integer in the array to minimum
    // for loop that  compares current integer to current min
    for (c=1; c<= count; c++){
        //if integer at current array address is less than the current min, replace it
        if (array[c] < temp)
            temp = array[c];
    }
    return temp;        // return the minimum integer value of the array
}

/*
Function name: stDev
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Output: the standard deviation of the integers in the array
Description: This function serves to find the standard deviation of the array
             by comparing every integer to the mean value. The differences are
             squared and added together. Then the square root of the total is taken
             which is the standard deviation
*/
float stDev (int count, int array[]){
    float temp = 0.0, average;           // declare variables as float
    int c;                      // declare counter as int
    average = avg(count, array);   // call function to get average value of the array integers
    // for loop that compares the values of every integer to the mean, squares them, and adds them together
    for (c=0; c< count; c++){
        temp = pow(average - array[c], 2) + temp;
    }
    temp = sqrt(temp / c);     // take the square root of the total to find standard deviation

    return temp;                // return the standard deviation of the array integers
}

/*
Function name: printArray
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Output: prints the array
Description: This function serves to print the integer values of the array
*/
void printArray (int count, int array[]){
    int c;      // set counter to integer
    // for loop that prints the integer at the current array address prescribed by the for loop
    for (c=0; c<= count; c++){
        printf("%d ", array[c]);        // print the individual integers
    }
    printf("\n");                       // new line
}

/*
Function name: sortArray
Inputs: pointers for array and the number if integers in the array
Output: the integers in the array in order from lowest to highest
Description: This function serves to put the values of the array in
             order from lowest to highest
*/
void sortArray (int count, int array[]){
    int temp, c, d, cc;     // declare variables and counters to integer
    // primary for loop that makes the secondary loop run as many times as the array has values
    for (c=0; c<= count; c++){
        // for loop that compares side by side values for increasing values, if they are not increasing, swap them
        for (cc=0; cc< count; cc++){
            d= cc+1;        // set d to be one memory location higher than the the current counter value
            // if the integers are not in increasing order, swap them
            if (array[cc] > array[d]){
                temp = array[d];
                array[d] = array[cc];
                array[cc] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why doesn't `getArray` take `count` as an argument, like all the other functions?

Comment: Its set that way because the function can change the value of count if a negative number is entered. That seemed logical to me, and it works now that I changed my for loops to "c<count" instead of "c<=count".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all your `for` loops, you should use `c < count` as the repetition test. Some of them have `c <= count`, so they're doing an extra iteration, and reading beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I was in the mindset that my input was the problem, not my output.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C are indexed from 0, which you seem to understand. However, that means that if an array has size `N`, then valid indices are from `0` to `N - 1`. You are working with indices from `0` to `N` almost everywhere. Hence the extra garbage element.

This cycle in `avg` for example

```
for (c=0; c<= count; c++){
    temp = temp + array[c];     // add current value of the array to temp
}
```

suffers from the above error. It cycles from `0` to `count`, instead of cycling from `0` to `count - 1`. The continuation condition in such cycles should typically use a strict comparison

```
for (c = 0; c < count; c++){
```

For some unexplainable reason the cycle in your `stDev` is written correctly, while most of your similar cycles are incorrect.

Comment: Not everywhere. He did it right in `getArray` and `stDev`.